# nthchild for infinite number of instances

Tags: jquery

I am interested in using the nthchild command for an infinite number of instances. I created a slider with jQuery and I have created navigation buttons for each slide at the bottom.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="button1"></li>
        <li id="button2"></li>
        <li id="button3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I currently use jQuery to advance to the selected slide by clicking the selected button using this code with the cycle plugin.

```
$('#button1').click(function() { 
    $('#slides').cycle(0); 
    return false; 
}); 
$('#button2').click(function() { 
    $('#slides').cycle(1); 
    return false; 
});  
$('#button3').click(function() { 
    $('#slides').cycle(2); 
    return false; 
});
```

Instead of having to create one jQuery command for each slider button, I would like to have one command that makes each an active link. I thought that using the nthchild would work if I could do it with an infinite number of instances.

I tried this and it did not work.

```
$('#nav ul li:nth-child(n)').click(function(){

    $('#slides').cycle(n);
    return false;

});
```

If you have any idea on how to get it working with the nthchild or a different way to go about it, that would be great.

Comment: Not sure I get this, but all you need is `$('#nav ul li').click(function(){...}`, that will select all the li's, you don't need to target each one on it's own, and then use `$(this).index()` in the cycle function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#nav ul li').on('click', function(){   //select all list elements
    $('#slides').cycle($(this).index()+1);//index is zero based
    return false;
});
```

Comment: adeneo, I used your solution and it worked great. Since cycle() is zero based, I didn't need the +1. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this :

```
$('li[id^="button"]').click(function() { 
    $('#slides').cycle(parseInt(this.id.slice(6),10)-1); // extracts the number from the id
    return false; 
});
```

`'[id^="button"]'` selects all elements whose id starts with `button`.

Using the id is more reliable than using the index : you can have other elements in between this way.

Comment: dystroy, thanks for answering. I am going to look into your answer as well. Some of the things you suggested looked useful for other things I am working on. Thanks so much!